# D3 + AngularJS: trigger brush event on multiple SVGs programatically

Tags: d3.js

I am currently working on a Angular app and we are using D3 for visualization. I have a requirement where I get data in csv in the following format

```
y, x1, x2, x3, x4
10, 20, 30, 40, 50
11, 21, 31, 41, 51
```

Using Angular, I have created a directive for "Scatter Plot" that takes input paramaters - data (after parsing above CSV as JSON), xAxisName and yAxisName.

I have used the directive to draw 4 scatter plots one for each (x1 Vs y), (x2 Vs y), (x3 Vs y), (x4 Vs y).

Each of the scatter plot has brush event and is working.

My question and requirement is :  When user is brushing on say, SVG1,  how can I trigger brushing on the SVG2, SVG3, SVG4 for the same data points that user selected on SVG1 ?

Also, vice-versa, if user is brushing on SVG3, I would like to trigger brushing on SVG1, SVG2 and SVG4 for the data points selected on SVG3.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Update 1:

my brush event on a SVG is defined as below. How can I select all the SVGs?

```
brush.on("brush", function()
                            {
                                var ext = brush.extent()
                                //  draw dots on scatter plot - if dot is with in brush use radius 9.5 else 3.5
                                svg.selectAll(".dot")
                                    .data(data)
                                    .attr("class", "dot")
                                    .attr("r",
                                    function (d) {if (d[xAxisName] > ext[0,0][0] && d[xAxisName] < ext[1,1][0] &&  d[yAxisName] > ext[0,0][1] && d[yAxisName] < ext[1,1][1] )
                                        return 9.5;
                                    else
                                        return  3.5;}  )
                                    .attr("cx", xMap)
                                    .attr("cy", yMap)
                                    .style("fill", function (d) {
                                        if (d[xAxisName] > ext[0,0][0] && d[xAxisName] < ext[1,1][0] &&  d[yAxisName] > ext[0,0][1] && d[yAxisName] < ext[1,1][1] )
                                            return "#fff";
                                        else
                                            return color(cValue(d));
                                    });
```

Comment: In the brush handler, apply the change you'd normally apply only to the current SVG to the other SVGs as well.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I updated my question with the my brush event handler. Currently, it looks at the current SVG and re-draws circles in the brush area of that SVG.  I guess, I need to select all the SVGs and perform the same operation. How can I select all the SVGs ? Is there anything like d3.selectAll('svg').select('.dot') ??

Comment: Actually, i just tried d3.selectAll('svg').select('.dot'). Initially, all the scatter plots are rendered properly. When I started brushing on SVG2, it replaced all the other scatter plots (SV1, SV3, SVG4) with the items form SVG2.

Comment: You would need to pass in the proper `data` as well.

Comment: I am creating brush extent in the brush handler of each SVG. I need to trigger the "brush" event of other SVGs passing the same extent that I created for the SVG initiating the brush event. Basically, if SVG1 is initiating brush event, I create the brush.extent() and pass this extent and trigger brush events for other SVGs for SVG2, SVG3 etc... Also, in the brush handler I need to check to create a new extent or use the passed extent. But, I don't know how to implement this. Any thoughts?

Comment: Yes I know what you're trying to do. What I'm saying is that the problem you're seeing is because in your handler you're calling `.data(data)` with the data for the respective SVG. In order to make it work, you need to run this code with the right data for each SVG.

Comment: I need all the "data" for each SVG. It's only the extent that changes to highlight the selected circles.